# Adding of any html file from the minima/_includes directory into the website directory cause the github build to fail

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, minima

I wanted to override/change certain things in head.html so I copied to over https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/_includes/head.html to my website directory and built it (jekyll clean + build) - this worked fine in my local but on pushing the same to github the build fails with no particular error.

[Here](https://github.com/bishonbopanna/bishonbopanna.github.io/commit/988bfa422fd4054e0d4a089a4594a3b786434084) is my commit that fails in github

[This](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/issues/206) where i reported it.

Generic error that i get -

The page build failed for the master branch with the following error:

Page build failed. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-github-pages-builds/.

For information on troubleshooting Jekyll see:

https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-jekyll-builds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ***_config.yml*** file, add [jekyll-seo-tag](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-seo-tag/blob/master/docs/installation.md) plugin like this :

```
plugins:
  - jekyll-feed
  - jekyll-seo-tag
```